# Return string with help JSON (Java and Spring)

Tags: java, json, spring

I wrote code that should return the string in the reverse order, but I only managed to return the array and this is wrong

```
 @PostMapping("/reverse")
    public List<String> reverseList(@RequestBody String string) {
        List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(string.split("[+,]"));
        return IntStream.range(0, stringList.size())
                .mapToObj(i -> stringList.get(stringList.size() - 1 - i))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

сURL command

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "a1+a2+a3+a4" localhost:8080/hello/reverse
```

Output

```
["a4","a3","a2","a1"]
```

But this is wrong

Need to be returned like this

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "a1+a2+a3+a4" localhost:8080/hello/reverse
```

Output without array and commas

```
a4+a3+a2+a1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Spring will use `Jackson` to serialize objects returned from endpoints (in case of `RestController` at least) to JSON. To overcome this just return a `String` from your endpoint and use `Collectors.joining("+")` instead of `Collectors.toList` :

```
@PostMapping("/reverse")
public String reverseList(@RequestBody String string) {
    List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(string.split("[+,]"));
    return  IntStream.range(0, stringList.size())
            .mapToObj(i -> stringList.get(stringList.size() - 1 - i))
            .collect(Collectors.joining("+"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

```
@PostMapping("/reverse")
    public String reverseList(@RequestBody String string) {
        List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(string.split("[+,]"));
        return IntStream.range(0, stringList.size())
                .mapToObj(i -> stringList.get(stringList.size() - 1 - i))
                .collect(Collectors.joining("+"));
    }
```

If you want to send it as plain text then repalce the postmapping with this:

> @PostMapping("/reverse", produces =
>   org.springframework.http.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
{
    @PostMapping("/reverse", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String reverseList(@RequestBody String string) {
        List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(string.split("[+,]"));
        return  IntStream.range(0, stringList.size())
                .mapToObj(i -> stringList.get(stringList.size() - 1 - i))
}
```